# Como resolver o erro 150 da chave estrangeira na migration com laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou com problemas na criação da chave estrangeira na migration.

Estou trabalhando com PHP, LARAVEL 5.3 e MYSQL. 
Está me dando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo vai o meu código:

**Migration da Tabela categs**

```
class CreateCategsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('nome_cat');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categs');
    }
}
```

**Migration da Tabela produtos**

```
class CreateProdutosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('nome');
            $table->text('descricao');
            $table->integer('categs_id');
            $table->foreign('categs_id')->references('id')->on('categs');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('produtos');
    }
}
```

**Model categs**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categ extends Model
{
    //Relacionamento 1:n Categoria dos produtos

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\produtos');
    }
}
```

**Model produtos**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produtos extends Model
{
    //
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\categ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tira as aspas simples do nome da FK

Comment: Já tirei, e não resultou.

Comment: faça dessa forma e verifique se deu certo. `$table->integer('categs_id')->unsigned()`

Comment: Dica: é uma péssima ideia colocar foreign keys junto com criação de campos. Por padrão, sempre utilize uma migration para criação de campos e outra pra criação de foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao rodar o comando seed. O laravel adota a ordem dos arquivos como linha de execução de cima pra baixo. Ou seja, o `migrate` de `categs` deve estar antes do `migrate` dos `produtos`.

Por exemplo: as tabela *companies* tem relação `1-N` com *banks*, logo a *migrate* de *companies* deve estar acima do *migrate* *banks*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Schema::create('banks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('account');
    $table->integer('bank_agency');
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned(); //compaines_table.php
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
});
```

Comment: Alterei a data do migration categs de modos a ficar acima do migration produtos, mesmo assim, continua o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: no `migration` produtos, alterei de

```
$table->integer('categs_id'),
```

para

```
$table->unsignedinteger('categs_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de criar o campo de relacionamento:

```
$table->integer('categs_id', false, true);
```